# SQL: get A with max B for every distinct C

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

In my example, I have a table containing info about different venues, with columns for `city`, `venue_name`, and `capacity`.  I need to select the `city` and `venue_name` for the venue with the highest `capacity` within each `city`.  So if I have data:

```
city | venue  | capacity
LA   | venue1 | 10000
LA   | venue2 | 20000 
NY   | venue3 | 1000
NY   | venue4 | 500
```

... the query should return:

```
LA | venue2 
NY | venue3
```

Can anybody give me advice on how to accomplish this query in SQL?  I've gotten tangled up in joins and nested queries :P.  Thanks!

Comment: first, write a query that finds the max capacity grouped by city, then query for the venue that matches that city and capacity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.city, t.venue
  from tbl t
  join (select city, max(capacity) as max_capacity from tbl group by city) v
    on t.city = v.city
   and t.capacity = v.max_capacity
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with `not exists`:

```
select i.*
from info i
where not exists (select 1
                  from into i2
                  where i2.city = i.city and i2.capacity > i.capacity);
```

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is to `join` the table back to itself using a subquery with `max`:

```
select y.city, y.venue_name
from yourtable y
    join (select city, max(capacity) maxcapacity
          from yourtable
          group by city
    ) t on y.city = t.city and y.capacity = t.maxcapacity
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer apply to order those values and bring the results back to your main query.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607246/Making-OUTER-and-CROSS-APPLY-work-for-you

Another alternative would be to use the RowNum() function.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
SELECT 
  v.city, 
  Ranked.Venue,
  Ranked.Capacity   
FROM Venues v WITH (NOLOCK) 
   Outer Apply 
        ( 
           SELECT TOP 1 
                Venue, Capacity
            FROM Venues Ranked WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE v.City = Ranked.City 
            ORDER BY Capacity DESC 
         ) as Ranked 
 GROUP BY 
     v.city,
     Ranked.Venue,
     Ranked.Capacity
```